turning wireless interface off
I am creating a hardening tool where i need to turn off all the wireless interfaces,
is the command nmcli radio all off enough for that purpose, or should i be doing something extra, making some related module not loadable?
output of nmcli radio all after off is as following:
WIFI-HW  WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN
enabled  disabled  enabled  disabled

Edit: The hardening tool i am working on is a project for undergrad degree and i want build this tool to work for any ubuntu based system, for testing purpose, i have ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, desktop in a virtual box.

Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is it for desktop use or server? Is it a cloud instance or inside a virtual machine? Add these information in your question.

Please don't ask yes/no questions  nmcli radio all off that can be enough but only you can decide that ;)

@Rinzwind Hi, i am fairly new to Linux and all related stuff so can you please point to something like modules and directories that i can look into to get more info, I have checked /sys/class/net but didn't get much information. Thanks

nmcli radio all off can be undone with nmcli radio all on and you probably know that ... You probably want to additionally look into the output of lsmod | grep wifi | awk '{print $1}' | xargs modinfo

best done in the BIOS if you have that option,
